# Stop Site Redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I got a huge redirect problem, I set up a sub-domain

```
http://subdomain.myspace.com/
```

and copied a project over as well. Owned it, set chmod particular on 777 so me and the Designers can work on this one, this works fine. Problem is now, whenever I call the URL of this sub it redirects me to the

```
http://www.originalsite.de
```

original Site. Even when I take out the .htaccess AND replace the index.php, which is a hard way to go for it, it redirects me. For this is by far not the first time I do this, what makes me even more surprised. But what kind of redirect can this be?

No redirect via `.htaccess` nor via `index.php`. I know there's no code but the company I'm working at won't allow me to post the code.

I hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information on your setup to determine the cause of the redirect but i have a guess. If you have ruled out all the possible scenarios of a redirect being in existense (i.e. Htaccess, php etc) then check your caching. Chrome and Firefox sometimes cache dns and http requests. 
Try the following:

> Open an "incognito" window in chrome or "Private" in firefox, and try loading your subdomain.

1. If it still redirects, then you still have a hard redirect somewhere hidden (Perhaps in myspace settings)
2. If this works and does not redirect, then it's my guess above with caching (Clear everything and you should be fine - Plus disable prediction and navigation errors correction in your chrome settings)

Hope this helps

Comment: Man, its so easy and I didn't get it. Opened that sub in different Browsers yesterday, and nothing worked. But now it does, after opening in a private-mode FF-window. So I cleaned Browsercache(via FF not via strg+F5) and got a success.Thanks for helping me out on this one Angelos.Sometimes its hard to see the Forrest among the Trees...